# How can i align evenly?

Tags: flutter

*I am new in Flutter and trying to put SizedBox and container which had "validate" text EVENLY. But mainAxisAlignment after Column didn't work. There is still no space. Should i use sth else rather than mainAxis, could you please help me*

```
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            createPaymentPage(),
            SizedBox(width:400,height:200, child: Image.network('https://www.vippng.com/png/detail/424-4249192_credit-card-design-and-collaterals-black-credit-card.png'),
    ),
            new GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 150,
                height: 40,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  '   Validate',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  MapScreen()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly"? Can you provide a screen sample that contains your expected output?

Comment: Container( width: double.maxinfinity, child: Column()) use this

Comment: Please provide expected output image.